# Connect SourceTree to AWS CodeCommit on Windows

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, atlassian-sourcetree, aws-codecommit

I'm using Atlassian's SourceTree to work with git on Windows 10, and choose AWS CodeCommit as the remote hosting server.

I [followed](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/zh_cn/codecommit/latest/userguide/setting-up-https-unixes.html) this and couldn't find the issue.

Following is the error has given

```
git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false fetch origin
fatal: unable to access 'https://git-codecommit.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/repoName/': The requested URL returned error: 403
Completed with errors, see above.
```

Answer (score 6):

403 means permission denied: somehow your AWS credentials were not properly sent to the remote Amazon server.

The [part of the tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/zh_cn/codecommit/latest/userguide/setting-up-https-unixes.html#setting-up-https-unixes-credential-helper) involving credentials is:

```
git config --global credential.helper '!aws codecommit credential-helper $@'
git config --global credential.UseHttpPath true
```

> If you created a specific AWS credentials profile for AWS CodeCommit, you can specify which profile to use, such as CodeCommitProfile:

```
git config --global credential.helper '!aws --profile CodeCommitProfile codecommit credential-helper $@'
```

That is the part you need to double-check (`git config -l`). Make sure the prerequisite `aws configure` was doen properly first.

Comment: I try to use profile but  it always return 403 if I config using HTTPS Git credentials for AWS CodeCommit. however it works fine with profile if I config with user access id and key in Windows 10. Any advise on it?

Comment: @BaodiDi I am not sure: could you describe the difference between those two use case in more detail in a separate question?

Answer (score 1):

AWS CLI guide says to run:

```
git config --global credential.helper '!aws codecommit credential-helper $@'
```

Sourcetree doesn't have aws-cli in path, so you should instead use the exact path to aws-cli (this example is for Mac):

```
git config --global credential.helper '/usr/local/bin/aws codecommit credential-helper $@'
```

For windows the path would be something like `C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSCLIV2`

Answer (score 0):

It started happening for me, when my AWS password has expired and i had reset it. Locally git started giving me a 403 error because of outdated credentials. I was trying to connect to codecommit with my normal aws account login credentials , which again gave me the same 403 error. Finally i realized that i need to generate new git credentials through AWS account settings and use them . That solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

First create

```
aws configure --profile myprofile
```

and Add to Source tree edit configuration file to this
(Settings->Remote->EditConfig)

```
[credential "aws-repo-url"]
 helper = /opt/homebrew/bin/aws codecommit credential-helper --profile myprofile $@
 UseHttpPath = true
```